# SpringBootTest: Can't access JPA repository from new thread

Tags: spring-data-jpa, integration-testing, jdbctemplate, spring-boot-test

I have an autowired jpa repository object working in main thread. I can read to and write from it, see it in log message. However, I need to use repository from a new thread. After passing it to another thread, it fails with error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "my_schema.my_table" does not exist
```

There are  no problems with same repository in main thread.

```
import static org.awaitility.Awaitility.await;


@Autowired
MyRepository repository;

@Test
    @Sql(scripts = "/database/init.sql", 
         config = @SqlConfig(dataSource = "myDataSource", 
         transactionManager = "myTransactionManager"))
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "myTransactionManager",
            rollbackFor = Exception.class,
            propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void test() {
            repository.saveAndFlush(new TestObject("test"));
            log.info(repository.findAll().toString())
            await().atMost(TIMEOUT, SECONDS).until(() -> correctionRepository.findAll().size() == 1);
    }
```

In this example I use Awaitility class, but it doesn't matter. The same situation if I sending some message to a Kafka listener.

How can I use the repository across multiple threads ?

Comment: read from and write to*

Comment: typo: await().atMost(TIMEOUT, SECONDS).until(() -> repository.findAll().size() == 1);